# Is there a parametrization of a hyperbola $x^2-y^2=1$ by functions x(t) and y(t) both birational?

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections, projective-geometry, parametrization, birational-geometry

Consider the hyperbola $x^2-y^2=1$.
I am aware of some parametrizations like:

1. $(x(t),y(t))=(\frac{t^2+1}{2t},\frac{t^2-1}{2t})$;
2. $(x(t),y(t))=(\frac{t^2+1}{t^2-1},\frac{2t}{t^2-1})$;
3. $(x(t),y(t))=(\cosh t,\sinh t)$;
4. $(x(t),y(t))=(\sec(t),\tan(t))$;

The first and the second are by rational functions $x(t)$ and $y(t)$. But the functions are not birational(i.e. with rational inverse of each).

Is there a parametrization where:

- $x(t)$ is rational with inverse also rational, and
- $y(t)$ is rational with inverse also rational?

Is possible, to find a parametrization where both are rational and at least one of the has inverse rational?

Comment: Given that each $x$ with $|x|>1$ must occur twice in a complete parameterization, it can’t even have a single-valued inverse.

Comment: Ok. But, about a parametrization with y(t) rational with a inverse also rational? Also, is possible to chose a branch of a inverse to x which would be birational?

Comment: Each $y$ occurs twice, too, so, no. If you only parameterize one connected component, you **might** be able to make $y$ binational.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $(f(t),g(t))$ is a parameterization with $f$ and $g$ rational and $g^{-1}$ is rational, then:

$$\left(f\left(g^{-1}(s)\right),s\right)$$ is a parameterization and $f\circ g^{-1}$ is rational.

But $f\circ g^{-1}(s)=\sqrt{1+s^2}$ is not a rational function.

---

This works if we even just want  $(f(t),g(t))$ to parameterize any subset of the curve $x^2-y^2=1,$ for $t$ in some interval $(a,b).$

This same argument shows that $f$ can’t be birational if $g$ is rational.

Comment: Yes. That solves negatively the question. Thanks.